# Computing the optimal size of a LruCache

Tags: android

Is there a formula I could use to compute for the size of a `LruCache`?
Could I base it on the VM memory statistics offered by `Runtime.getRuntime()`.

I am storing bitmap files - the file data, and not the decompressed Bitmap.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an excerpt from [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) guide:

```
// Get memory class of this device, exceeding this amount will throw an
// OutOfMemory exception.
final int memClass = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(
        Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();

// Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, in the preceding paragraph, they have a lot more guidelines, but no specific answer.

Comment: The link's example code has been updated with the way it gets available memory and sets cacheSize. It now uses `final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);` and then does `final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;`

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking the wrong way around your problem. Instead of trying to make the cache fit the available memory, you should have the system remove things from the cache when memory goes down. And that is what [soft references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) are used for.

There are some available Java implementations for caches based on soft references like Googles [MapMaker](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), but I'm not sure how much footprint those libraries bring with them and if you maybe are better suited with a selfmade implementation on Android.

Comment: Android does not support `SoftReference`, by design. The VM needs to aggressively free up memory. The `LruCache` is the correct solution. It needs a size declared up-front.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20015

Comment: Ok, after reading that discussion I don't know what to say. Why on earth do those people copy the Java classes when they suddenly change important aspects of the behaviour...